# Prevent XSS in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, security, ckeditor

I want to save my application from attack so I wanted to disable any type of execution in my CKEditor config, so I found a solution that is `allowContent: false` which prevents the `<scripts>` tags inside CKEditor but after putting `<p><a href="javascript:(alert(document.domain))">XSS</a></p>` in the CKEditor so it executes the js inside `href`.

config

```
config = {
   ...,
   allowContent: false
}
```

now the below script doesn't work after putting the above config:

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

I also wanted to prevent below js inside `href` but currently, it executing

```
<p><a href="javascript:(alert(document.domain))">XSS</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sanitize the data inputed to the CKEditor. The `config.htmlEmbed.sanitizeHtml` of CKEditor option allows plugging an external sanitizer.

In my opinion, the best sanitizer available for now is [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) library.

Here is more info on including DOMPurify in CKEditor: [more info](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html-embed.html).

In my opinion, it is very hard to secure CKEditor "by yourself", so better use sanitizer. There was some security issues in this software, an interesting example described here: [CKEditor XSS](https://research.securitum.com/the-curious-case-of-copy-paste/)

Comment: Do you know of a similar library for .Net (Server side)? While it's true that you should always sanitize the html on the ouput side, it will also be good to sanitize and minimize the risk in the input side.